# Owl Carousel Transitions Effect Not Working After Chrome Latest Update (V36)

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, css-transitions, owl-carousel

i'm using the OWl carousel for a while everything were perfect but recently i faced a issue after my chrome browser update. The css transition effects are not working anymore on chrome.

But all effects working fine on firefox.

Anyone can help me..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have found the Solution friends.

Here is that..

Replacing the below line of code

`support3d = (asSupport !== null && asSupport.length >= 1 && asSupport.length <= 2);`

instead of

`support3d = (asSupport !== null && asSupport.length === 1);`

This Solved My Problem. Now CSS Transitions Working Fine on All Browsers.

Comment: this line is not present in owl.carousel.js for the new version... Cant find a similar line...

Comment: @David What Version you are using now. In new version (v1.3.3), Line No: 804.

Comment: Version : 2.0 beta 2.4

Comment: My misstake: forgot to import owl.animate.js and css

Comment: @zlen Have you replaced the above code? I'm also using v1.3.3 and working fine...

Comment: Yeah. But I replaced it handly. Î'll try by an other way this evening

Comment: @zlen If you have a Demo Link pls give I'll check the problem

Answer (score 3):

In version 1.3.3 replace this:

```
support3d = (asSupport !== null && asSupport.length === 1);
```

in line 804 with this:

```
support3d = (asSupport !== null && asSupport.length >= 1 && asSupport.length <= 2);
```

Then it should work out just fine!

Answer (score 0):

For the convenient, I've created a branch for it, easy to merge, easy to download:
https://github.com/lib-issue/OwlCarousel/tree/stackoverflow_25153801

It's possible to use:

```
support3d = (asSupport !== null && asSupport.length !== 0);
```

as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was an issue in the Owl.Carousel 2 version. The carousel does't work in Chrome. Then I added this line in my script. The slider is now working fine in all browsers on my end.

Please add `var $ = jQuery.noConflict();` in your script file.

ex.

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).ready(funnction() {

//your script goes to here

});
```